# Python define_Thread_Count

Tags: python, multithreading

I am just learning about threading in Python.  I have a basic script running but am having trouble with how to define the thread count.  Right now I have something like this:

```
def my_fun(x):
    do something
    with open('filename', 'a') as f:
        f.write(results)

for nodes in node_list:
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_fun, args=(x,))
    my_thread.start()
```

This works but there are 179 nodes in the node_list so it creates 179 threads.  How can I create less threads yet still accomplish getting every node from the list and running the function on them?  The function logs into each node using ssh, runs a show command and outputs the results to a file.

Comment: Python version 2 or 3?

Comment: Python version 3.5

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor